# Proof that $[\overline{\mathbb Q}:\mathbb R\cap\overline{\mathbb Q}]=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have to prove that for the algebric closure of $\mathbb Q$ above $\mathbb C$, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the dimension of $\mathbb{R}\cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is equal to $2$.

I have tried to use the dimension theorem, that says: 
$$[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]=[\mathbb{C}:\overline{\mathbb{Q}}]\cdot [\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{R}\cap\overline{\mathbb{Q}}]\cdot[\mathbb{R}\cap\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{R}]=2$$

but I am not quite sure about it because $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}\cap\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ does not imply that
$$[\mathbb{C}:\overline{\mathbb{Q}}]=[\mathbb{R}\cap\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{R}]=1.$$

Am I right?

Comment: $[\mathbb C:\overline{\mathbb Q}]$ is infinite, while $[\mathbb R\cap\overline{\mathbb Q}:\mathbb R]$ is not well-defined, since $\mathbb R\cap\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is not an extension of $\mathbb R$. Your proof doesn't work.

Comment: what i need to do to proof this statment?

Comment: The simplest way to do that is to use the definition of degree in this case. Hint: show $\{1,i\}$ is a basis.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Let $z=x+yi \in \mathbb{C}$, with $x,y \in \mathbb R $. Prove that $z \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}} \implies \bar z \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}} \implies x,y \in \mathbb R\cap\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer: $i+0 \cdot i$ is in $\bar{\Bbb Q}$ but $x=i$ is not real.

Comment: @Watson, $x,y \in \mathbb R$... See my edited answer. Thanks for the push.